# throws some error while loading a text file for data analysis last 2 line throws an error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

throws some error while loading a text file for data analysis last 2 line throws an error

```
import numpy as np
f=open('decision_tree_data.txt','r')
x_train=[]
y_train=[]
for line  in f:
line = np.asarray(line.split(),dtype=np.float32)
x_train.append(line[:-1])
y_train.append(line[:-1])
x_train = np.asmatrix(x_train)
y_train = np.reshape(y_train,(len(y_train),1))
```

Comment: _What_ error does it throw?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape',,,,,ValueError
      1 x_train = np.asmatrix(x_train)2 y_train = np.reshape(y_train,(len(y_train),1))
       except (AttributeError, TypeError):
--->          return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 56 into shape (14,1)

Comment: Please add the error to the question in proper format and not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check indentation of your code.Following code successfully compiles for me and also make sure you have installed the numpy module.

```
import numpy as np
f=open('decision_tree_data.txt','r')
x_train=[]
y_train=[]

for line in f:
    line=np.asarray(line.split(),dtype=np.float32)
    x_train.append(line[:-1])
    y_train.append(line[-1])

x_train=np.asmatrix(x_train)
y_train=np.reshape(y_train,(len(y_train),1))
```

Comment: #1) valueError: cannot reshape array of size 56 into shape (14,1) #2)AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'